# Flash Builder как переключить из режима: «Код» на режим «Дизайн»?

Tags: flash

Flash Builder 4.6 как переключить из  режима: «Код» на режим «Дизайн»?

[image: Flash Builder 4.6]

Answer (score 1):

Flash Builder крайне глюченный, на слабых компах(например, у меня) - очень тормозит.

ИМХО Используй лучше FlashDevelop.